# The most vs. Most

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like others to explain this to me.
Which one is correct?

- What I like the most about my family is...
- What I like most about my family is...

Thank you!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Heloo:

**Most is a superlative form, and before superlative forms come an article 'The'.

Hence the former is correct.**

Comment: however logical that might seem, it is not how native speakers would express the thought. To my ear (native BrE speaker) there is nothing to choose between the two versions. If I were wanted to express such a thought I would marginally prefer the second version, but if someone used the first version I would not regard it as odd.

Answer (score 2):

To my ear (native BrE speaker) there is nothing to choose between the two versions. If I were wanted to express such a thought I would marginally prefer the second version, but if someone used the first version I would not regard it as odd.

You can use "most" or "the most" in this context.