# Suffer most vs. Suffer the most

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Which sentence is correct?

> During the storm, those in private homes *suffered most* or *suffered
> the most*.

Are both equally accepted as grammatical in English?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The most vs. Most](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183851/the-most-vs-most). But the accepted answer there is wrong.  In this context you can use either "most" or "the most" with almost no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As what James has commented, both versions are used.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Suffer+most%2Csuffer+the+most&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) shows that *suffer most* was more common of the two for about 180 years before this millennium.